# Echo each $value and $variable in span

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, code-snippets

the context

[image]

I would like to output my snippet this way

Price : 2,330 **$**

what I want to do is give a class and surround price and currency by span like that

```
$value = <span class="price"> number_format(floatval($value), 0 ) </span> . <span class="currency"> $variable = get_field('currency', 'option')</span>;
```

but it doesn't work like that...how to make html and give a css class inside my php snippet ?

to be able to css them individually

how to do it with my snippet inside `$value =` ?

```
add_filter('acf/format_value/name=price', 'acf_number_comma_decimal_for_currency_field', 20, 3);

    function acf_number_comma_decimal_for_currency_field($value, $post_id, $field) {
    if(empty($value)) { return 'Price: Contact US'; }
    $value = number_format(floatval($value), 0 )  . $variable = get_field('currency', 'option'); 
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/name=surface', 'acf_number_comma_decimal_for_surface_field', 20, 3);

  function acf_number_comma_decimal_for_surface_field($value, $post_id, $field) {
  if (get_field('$value')) { $value = number_format(floatval($value), 0) . $variable = get_field('symbol', 'option');}
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: have you try the code ?

Comment: yes i tried different ways but it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: hello nico
what I want to do is give a class and surround price and currency by span
like that
`$value = <span class="price"> number_format(floatval($value), 0 ) </span> . <span class="currency"> $variable = get_field('currency', 'option')</span>;`

but it doesn't work like that...how to make html and give a css class inside my php snippet ? this is the main problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that **$value** and **$variable** have values from php code like this (by assignment or return from a function

```php
<?php
$value = funct1();
$variable = funct2();
?>

<span class="surface"><?php echo $value;?></span> 
<span class="symbol"><?php echo $variable;?></span>
```

Once you are in html, you need to drop into php via the

```php
<?php
```

and echo the variable and the switch back to html via

```php
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply
I was rather thinking of a solution to do it in one line here

`$value = number_format(floatval($value), 0 )  . $variable = get_field('currency', 'option'); ` 

at least just surround it
how to insert class or html inside

Comment: You can do whichever way you want. Its an example of how to structure it